# I cant get my state updated synchronously and it just performs on next render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want my react states to be updated immediately as soon as I refactor the data in them so that I can run the functions in correct order, otherwise, when it performs the next function I declared, it will just execute the `undefined` or `null` data since its not yet updated.

How can I fix this issue? I know some will say that states are not made for this and have to be used asynchronously but I don't know how I can else make that work out and let the users get logged in and redirect to their profile page only when they type correct users credentials, this might not sound a big deal for most of you but I'm just new to react and have been dealing with that for the last few days passed, basically users should be able to granted for the profile page only when they successfully log in and otherwise should get an error..

But, to get it running perfectly, `currentUser` has to be populated through the credentials taken from the `userInput` and `passInput` states just before the next function, which is `useEffect`, feeling so stuck with that and any help will be very appreciated

[link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-sea-us2e9i?file=/src/pages/Login.tsx)

```
https://github.com/Abdulberk/frontend-auth
```

```js
type User = {
  username: String | null;
  password: String | null;
}

function Login() {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState<String | null>("");
  const [passInput, setPassInput] = useState<String | null>("");
  const [isLoggedin, setIsLoggedin] = useState<Boolean>(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<Boolean>(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState<Boolean>(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<String | null>("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User>({
    username: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const submitHandler = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    setCurrentUser(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        username: userInput,
        password: passInput
      }
    });

    setCount(prev => prev + 1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/login", {
      email: currentUser.username,
      password: currentUser.password
    })
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<any, any>) => {
        console.log(response)
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log("user exists");
          setIsLoading(false);
          setIsLoggedin(true)
          setAuth(response.data.token)
          setCount(prev => prev + 1)
        } else {
          console.log("user does not exist");
          setIsLoading(false);
          setIsLoggedin(false);
          setAuth(null)
          setCount(prev => prev + 1)
        }
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        setAuth(prev => prev)
        setIsLoggedin(false)
        setIsLoading(false);
        setCount(prev => prev + 1)
      })
  }, [currentUser.username, currentUser.password])

  if (isLoggedin) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("redirecting to profile page");
      navigate(`users/${currentUser.username}`, { state: currentUser });
    }, 2000);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`${count} renders`);
  }, [count])

  return (
    <div>
      <Form>
        <LoginContainer>
          <LoginImageContainer>
            <LoginImage src={require('../right.png')}/>
          </LoginImageContainer>

          <LoginTitle>Login your account</LoginTitle>
      
          <InputContainer >
            <FaUserCircle 
              fontSize="30px"
              color="#747474"
              style={{ position: "absolute", top: "50%", transform: "translateY(-50%)", left: "20px" }}
            /> 
            
            <LoginInput
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setUserInput(e.target.value)} 
              placeholder="Username"
            />
          </InputContainer>
    
          <InputContainer >
            <RiKeyFill style={{ left: "20px", top: "50%", transform: "translateY(-75%)", color: "#747474", fontSize: "32px", position: "absolute" }} />
            
            <LoginInput
              placeholder="Password" 
              style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setPassInput(e.target.value)} 
            />
          </InputContainer>
        
          <Button 
            onClick={submitHandler} 
            className={isLoading? 'lds-dual-ring': undefined}
            type='submit'
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#7FBCD2", marginBottom: "20px" }}
            size="lg"
            variant="primary"
          >
            {!isLoading ? "Login" : undefined}
          </Button>
        </LoginContainer>
      </Form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Why don't you redirect to `profile` page inside the `if (response.status=== 200)` clause?

Comment: @Shuvo tried it out now, still the same issue. I just want to it do without using useEffect but not sure how it would be then..

Comment: @berk the sandbox link is a bunch of empty components, do you mind making it something usable I might have a suggestion for you

Comment: The codesandbox is incomplete and not runnable. It's also not clear what exactly you say is the issue. React state updates ***aren't*** immediate, they are enqueued and asynchronously processed, but I don't see where you are trying to set a state and read the value immediately after. Please more clearly explain the issue, what you are trying to accomplish, and fix the sandbox so it's runnable and reproduces the issue you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I gave it a try even though your sandbox was empty. Check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-chandrasekhar-yvykcb). It's a stripped out version of what you shared here.

The gist of it is that your login attempt pattern is odd. The submit handler should be submitting the login with the current state and the input onChange should be updating the currentUser directly.

On top of that your redirect should be handled in a useEffect. Let me know if you have questions or I missed something!

Comment: hey gabriel, thanks a lot for your interest, just added a repo in my github for you to give a try and see detailed whats wrong, all those dependenciens was just added now in there, thanks a lot again...

Comment: Alright just check out the sandbox and let me know if that approach solves the issue. I was able to use the creds from your repo and added some divs to show if the log in was successful. Up to you to reuse that logic as you see fit.

Comment: yeah sure, that just worked out great ! as you also said there was someting wrong my code logic and this one you brought up seems more logical, really appreciated very much for taking your time to help me..hope i can help you with something soon :)

Comment: by the way, that "finally" you added in the  end of "then catch" block was what i was looking for exactly, to get my isLoading state running properly, thanks for that as well, i had totally forgotten about it